# Wrapping the EXPECT_NE, EXPECT_EQ into a validation function

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest

I have a few unit tests that validate whether certain values equate to 0 or not. In some cases, they're supposed to be 0 and in some, they're not.

Just like the following: `testA` expects `valueA` to not contain 0 whereas `testB` expects `valueB` to not.

What I am looking to do is to somehow wrap the validation part in a function so instead of invoking `EXPECT_NE`/`EXPECT_EQ` for each member, I just invoke a function that takes care of the validation part.

```
TEST(UnitTest, testA)
{
    Object object;
    // do stuff that modified object's values
    EXPECT_NE(object.valueA, 0);
    EXPECT_EQ(object.valueB, 0); 
}

TEST(UnitTest, testB)
{
    Object object;
    // do stuff that modified object's values
    EXPECT_EQ(object.valueA, 0);
    EXPECT_NE(object.valueB, 0); 
}
```

This is what I came up with but it's a bit too verbose. Wondering if there's a better approach to it?

```
void Validate(Object* obj, bool valA, bool valB)
{
    // verify valueB
    if (valA)
    {
        EXPECT_EQ(object->valueA, 0);
    }
    else
    {
        EXPECT_NE(object->valueA, 0);
    }

    // verify valueB
    if (valB)
    {
        EXPECT_EQ(object->valueB, 0); 
    }
    else
    {
        EXPECT_NE(object->valueB, 0); 
    }
}

TEST(UnitTest, testA)
{
    Object object;
    // do stuff that modified object's values
    Validate(&object, false, true);
}

TEST(UnitTest, testB)
{
    Object object;
    // do stuff that modified object's values
    Validate(&object, true, false);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### With `FieldsAre` and structured binding

With C++17 and a recent GoogleTest version ([>= v1.12.0](https://github.com/google/googletest/commit/a4621888650aaae118de93f9faf8ef5a18cab303)), you can simply use `FieldsAre()`, in case `Object` allows [structured binding](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding) (see [live example](https://godbolt.org/z/fE75GbeGT)):

```
using ::testing::FieldsAre;
using ::testing::Eq;
using ::testing::Ne;

struct Object
{
    int valueA;
    int valueB;
};

TEST(UnitTest, testA)
{
    Object object{42,0};
    EXPECT_THAT(object, FieldsAre(Ne(0), Eq(0)));
}

TEST(UnitTest, testB)
{
    Object object{0, 42};
    EXPECT_THAT(object, FieldsAre(Eq(0), Ne(0)));
}
```

### With a combination of matchers

Otherwise (if your GoogleTest is too old or `Object` does not allow structured binding), you can write a simple matcher-like function:

```
using ::testing::Field;
using ::testing::AllOf;

template <class M1, class M2>
auto MatchesValues(M1 m1, M2 m2)
{
    return AllOf(Field(&Object::valueA, m1), Field(&Object::valueB, m2));
}
```

and use it just like `FieldsAre` ([live example](https://godbolt.org/z/5KvWas97r)):

```
TEST(UnitTest, testA)
{
    Object object{42,0};
    EXPECT_THAT(object, MatchesValues(Ne(0), Eq(0)));
}

TEST(UnitTest, testB)
{
    Object object{0, 42};
    EXPECT_THAT(object, MatchesValues(Eq(0), Ne(0)));
}
```

### With a custom matcher

As noted in the comment, your original `Object` is a template, in which case `Field` cannot be used. In this case you can write a proper customer matcher like so ([live example](https://godbolt.org/z/r6a8z4soM)):

```
template<typename T>
struct Object
{
    int valueA;
    int valueB;
    T otherStuff;
    
    Object(int a, int b) : valueA(a), valueB(b) {}
};

MATCHER_P2(MatchesValues, m1, m2, "")
{
    return ExplainMatchResult(m1, arg.valueA, result_listener) 
        && ExplainMatchResult(m2, arg.valueB, result_listener);
}

TEST(UnitTest, testA)
{
    Object<int> object{42,0};
    EXPECT_THAT(object, MatchesValues(Ne(0), Eq(0)));
}
```

Comment: That's pretty neat but my example isn't exactly the same as what I tried cause I had a feeling it would be unrelated, but when I tried the 1st approach in my code, I get `In template: cannot decompose class type 'Object<int>': both it and its base class 'ObjectBase<int>' have non-static data members`

Comment: @xyf See my edit with `MatchesValues()`. Your `Object` does not allow for structured binding. If the access to the variables is considerably more complex, you can make `MatchesValues()` also full blown matcher (`MATCHER_P2`).

Comment: What if the `Object` is a template? I gave it a shot but haven't gotten far enough: https://godbolt.org/z/E7KnrrceK

Comment: @xyf See my updated answer, where I show an example with `MATCHER_P2`.